# Angular manual bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible for me to add angular files like

```
var scriptElem= document.createElement("script");
            scriptElem.src="scripts/app.js?v="+ version;
            scriptElem.type = "text/javascript";
            document.body.appendChild(scriptElem);
```

I need to add all of the controllers, directives through script and bootstrap manually but it does not work. It does not load the angular code at all.  I get the error of module not found. Thank you,

Comment: Because for your angular code to work, you need to resolve all your depedencies.

Comment: @Pramod_Para can you explain a bit more please.. have been stuck at this for a while now.

Comment: Could you please provide your complete code or plunkr, so that i can help you understand

Comment: ok i will create a plunkr

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqWbEv .    @Pramod_Para

Comment: Which part isn't working? The bootstrapping or loading the scripts?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen it adds the scripts to the page, but does not get loaded but if i added files direclty to the homepage, it works. So bootstrapping must be fine, the script does not seem to be loading though it is added to the page.

Comment: Have you included code to manually bootstrap angular? It would be easier if you could share a bit more.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqWbEv   ..that must explain something. What i am trying to do is, i need to create a extension at at each angular files like app.js?v=version in order to force brwser to fetch new files. The version of the file comes from the API request and then, i have to add it to every files as query string . Bascially, if theres a way in which i could assign a variable to src attr in script, that would solve my problem but that seems to be only coming if i add file from javascripts and so i have to add all of the files in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bootstrap your angular app first.As you have mentioned you want to use manual bootstrap then you can manually initialized your angular app by using `angular.bootstrap()` function. This function takes the modules as parameters and should be called within `angular.element(document).ready()` function. The `angular.element(document).ready()` function is fired when the DOM is ready for manipulation.
e.g

```
<html> 
<body> 
<div ng-controller="Ctrl"> Hello {{msg}}! </div> 
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script> 

<script> var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) { 
   $scope.msg = 'World'; }); //manual bootstrap process  a 
   angular.element(document).ready(function () { 
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']); 
   }); 
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

note-
1) You should not use the ng-app directive when manually bootstrapping your app.
2) You should not mix up the automatic and manual way of bootstrapping your app. 
3) Define modules, controller, services etc. before manually bootstrapping your app as defined in above example.

Comment: although late, thats the solution i followed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code It should work

```
var wrap = document.createElement('div');
    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.src = scriptUrl;
    scr.type = 'text/javascript';
    wrap.appendChild(scr);
    document.body.appendChild(wrap);
```

Comment: it didnt work, what difference would it make by that..just confused

Comment: script tag is included within the div, It is working with my local. the problem may be the URL please debug and check what exact src has been created and let me know I'll be happy if I could help.